# How to execute a .vbs file in a linux OS from java

Tags: java, linux

I have a .vbs file that makes the conversion of a docx file to a pdf type file, i run this .vbs from java in windows. Since i need this program running in a linux based OS i don't know if this solution would work.

the .vbs and the java code that i use for the project is here in this link: http://mydailyjava.blogspot.mx/2013/05/converting-microsoft-doc-or-docx-files.html

Note: I tried other solutions to convert the docx file to a pdf, but these solutions (docx4j, xdocreports, jodConverter) causes loss of format in the final pdf file, so those apis are not an option.

Comment: You can not possible get the same result from the vbs script even if you manage to have a vbs interpreter in linux. The conversion is heavily dependent on windows & office libraries.

Comment: VBScript can not run on linux natively. You can create a shell script using some alternatives, look at this post at askubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/396825/convert-docx-to-pdf

Comment: Have you tried `unoconv` from LibreOffice/OpenOffice ?

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely that you would be able to run the mentionned programs on Linux, since for that you would need:

- Microsoft Word installed, to open the Word file and print it
- Microsoft scripting host, to execute the vbs script
- A batch script interpreter that can access the scripting host

Since all these items are Microsoft software, they don't run natively on Linux.

So you will have to find alternatives as suggested by vzamanillo, or maybe find a way to run this in a WINE environment, but then that's not really Linux.

Comment: im going to try using  unoconv from LibreOffice, but i need an alternative method to convert those files, maybe some library in java...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing this from java, if you are open to using 3rd party software you could try [jWordConvert](http://www.qoppa.com/wordconvert/).